# Fast serialize / deserialize table (no recursion) in Lua

Tags: lua

I am using Lua 5.2. I am receiving large tables (1-dimensional array) of size 800,000. I want to dump these tables quickly. I found an article on wiki titled [Save Table To File](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SaveTableToFile) and used it but found not up to the mark. A sample table saved using this method, i.e., `table.save(table, filename)` is shared in my DropBox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/efdfvgy1n4m0zbx/table.dump?dl=0). (File is too large to put here. 8MB approx)

Since my primary concern is speed, I am ready to adopt binary serialization if such exists.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by “number and table together”. Even better, provide sample data to be serialized - this would give everyone a standard by which to compare their algorithm solutions.

Comment: In order to make the question simpler, I have slightly modified it and provided the sample data.

Comment: Can you use C libraries?

Comment: I can! It would require more efforts. Though I am not sure yet. Can you please provide detailed information about it?

Comment: Try my lpack at http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/index.html#lpack

Comment: @lhf: I downloaded the module however not able to find out the way to serialize/deserialize Lua table into a file. Can you provide the details, please?

Answer (score 1):

Are you bound to Lua 5.2? 5.3 introduced bitwise operators and built-in binary pack/unpack operations (see chapter 13, “Bits and Bytes”, of Programming in Lua, 4th edition). There are also specific algorithms and recommendations for serializing tables in chapter 15, “Data Files and Serialization”. These chapters will be your best source of information for a proper implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I can't use Lua 5.3 in this case.